# Jest Enzyme returns "TypeError: Cannot read property '_isMockFunction' of undefined"

Tags: react-redux, jestjs, enzyme

Trying to write a test that makes sure `handleClick()` is called, but I get the following error: `TypeError: Cannot read property '_isMockFunction' of undefined`.

Here is the component I'm testing (mostly), and the test code I'm running using Jest and Enzyme.

```js
import React from 'react';
import localize from '../data/Localize';
import translations from './translations';

class Category extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  handleClick(productInfo) {
    // do stuff
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <a
          onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this, productInfo)}
        >
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default localize(Category, translations);
```

`localize` returns the component in a given language based on the state.

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import {
  render,
  mount,
} from 'enzyme';
import configureStore from 'store';
import { setLocale } from 'actions';
import { locales } from 'test/testUtils';
import Category from '../Category';

describe(`Category Component`, () => {
  for (const locale of locales) {
    const store = configureStore();
    store.dispatch(setLocale(locale));

    it(`calls handlesClick in ${locale}`, () => {
      const handleClick = jest.spyOn(Category.prototype, `handleClick`);

      const wrapper = mount(
        <Provider store={store}>
          <Category />
        </Provider>
      );

      wrapper.update();
      wrapper.find(`a`).simulate(`click`);
      expect(handleClick).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
  }
});
```

The component will pass snapshots and they out correctly. However, I'm not having luck with this test. How do I get Jest/Enzyme to validate that `handleClick()` is getting called onClick?

Comment: you need to export class Category extends React.Component as well

Comment: @Eran can you please describe a little bit about your suggestion.

Comment: It seems you are only exporting the connected component ( export default localize(Category, translations); )          and you are testing the React core component    <Category /> .   ,  Category should also be exported :    export class Category

Answer (score 0):

You need to export your component twice. Once so your application can run the way you intend (using localize or connect if you're using redux), and again so you can test the component without the scope of the exported component conflicting with the scope of the component you would like to test.

Try this:

```
export class Category extends React.Component {}
```

In your test import the component as an object:

```
import { Category } from '../Category';
```